# Same domain only : smtp; 5.1.0 - Unknown address error 530-'SMTP authentication is required

Tags: email, smtp, email-bounces

I have a very strange problem after moving my netwave.be domain from WebHost4Life to Arvixe.

I configured several email adresses, like steven@netwave.be and sandra@netwave.be.

For POP3 I can use mail.netwave.be, a mailserver hosted by Arvixe.

However, for SMTP I **have to use** relay.skynet.be. Skynet (Belgacom) is one of the biggest internet providers in Belgium and blocks smtp requests to external mailservers. So for years I've been using relay.skynet.be to send my messages using steven@netwave.be as the sender. The worked perfectly.

After moving my domain to Arvixe, this is no longer the case.

I can send emails to people, no problem.
I have received emails too, so I suspect that's ok too.

But I can't send emails from one user of my domain to another user.

For example, if I send a mail from steven@netwave.be to sandra@netwave.be, relay.skynet.be picks up the mail just fine. A few seconds later, I get a 'Delivery Status Notification (Failure)' mail that contains:

> Reporting-MTA: dns; mailrelay012.isp.belgacom.be
>
> Final-Recipient: rfc822;sandra@netwave.be
>
> Action: failed
>
> Status: 5.0.0 (permanent failure) Remote-MTA: dns; [69.72.141.4]
>
> Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 5.1.0 - Unknown address error 530-'SMTP
>   authentication is required.' (delivery attempts: 0)

Like I said, this only seems to be the case when both the sender and recipient are adresses of a domain hosted by Arvixe.

I have serveral accounts not related to Arvixe at all. I can use relay.skynet.be to send mail to steven@netwave.be using these accounts. Likewise, I can use relay.skynet.be to send mail from steven@netwave.be to these accounts. but not from one Arvixe account to another.

I hope I have clearly outlined the problem and someone will be able to help me.

Comment: Did you solve that? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: The only way to resolve this is by talking to Arvixe. Nobody else can explain why their systems act the way they do (though I would suspect it's an antispam measure).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how one particular ISP is configuring their systems, and can only be resolved by talking to their support.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the mail server at 69.72.141.4 requires SMTP authorization for any/all outbound messages that go through it. Normally I would have suggested running a telnet test but since your ISP blocks outbound traffic on port 25, I did it myself.  Here's what I got:

```
[bob@foo ~]$ telnet 69.72.141.4 25
Trying 69.72.141.4...
Connected to 69.72.141.4.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 Welcome to the dodder SMTP server.
ehlo test.com
250-dodder.arvixe.com
250-SIZE 1410065408
250 AUTH LOGIN
mail from:<steven@netwave.be>
250 OK
rcpt to:<sandra@netwave.be>
530 SMTP authentication is required.
quit
```

Interesting eh? So then I tried sending a message as steven@netwave.be to anywhere:

```
[bob@foo ~]$ telnet 69.72.141.4 25
Trying 69.72.141.4...
Connected to 69.72.141.4.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 Welcome to the dodder SMTP server.
ehlo test.com
250-dodder.arvixe.com
250-SIZE 1410065408
250 AUTH LOGIN
mail from:<steven@netwave.be>
250 OK
rcpt to:<someotheraddress@somedomain.com>
530 SMTP authentication is required.
```

It's the same error this time too.

The reason why it seems to be working when sending to other domains is because those other emails aren't ever going through this server (they're using your ISP's mail relay). I'd suggest contacting Arvixe and see what they advise doing.

Comment: I second contacting Arvixe. It may be that, as an antispam measure, they are refusing emails with both the sender and the recipient in their domains unless the sender is authenticating.

Answer (score 0):

As `mail.netwave.be` does not accept mails from it's own domain without authentication, how about using authentication? ;-)

Most ISPs who sell you "Internet" without port 25 do this to prevent spam sent via malware/botnes on their customers machines (terrible, terrible technique). In most cases, port 587/submission is still open.

[Mail Submission](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4409) is designed for authenticated users to send their mail, without hitting the same restrictions as non-authenticated users on port 25 (even if most servers accept authentication on port 25 too).

`mail.netwave.be` has port 587 open, could you try using this to circumvent the port 25 block by your ISP?